# Tools for validating JSON to import into Firebase

Tags: json, validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import JSON data via file upload into Firebase, however running into an error message:

```
"Error parsing JSON data. Please validate your input."
```

Any recommendations for tools to validate this JSON and find the issue?

Comment: There are several online JSON validators, such as http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) pretty much

Comment: Try to validate your JSON: https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator.

Note : 
Make sure in your each key special character not present

In my case I used "." in my key, thus my JSON is not valid

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize JSON directly.

Grab [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older browsers.

Use a try/catch block to parse the JSON

```
function parse(value) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
        return { error: e };
    }
}
```

If the catch block receives an error, it's invalid, handle it accordingly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/BvWtU/